# Store a trie on Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) to store a trie, for two reasons:

1. It seems very tempting because it lends itself easily to a trie!
2. Im not sure how I'd do this otherwise, on some other hosted database solution

Im hesitating to be impulsive about this decision because of what I read on [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data), to quote:

> Avoid nesting data Because the Firebase Realtime Database allows
>   nesting data up to 32 levels deep, you might be tempted to think that
>   this should be the default structure. However, when you fetch data at
>   a location in your database, you also retrieve all of its child nodes.
>   In addition, when you grant someone read or write access at a node in
>   your database, you also grant them access to all data under that node.
>   Therefore, in practice, it's best to keep your data structure as flat
>   as possible.

This SO Post concerns me still thinking of storing a trie, but also verifying my understanding how exactly a read/fetch occurs on Firebase

So lets for example assume three hashes: abcd, abcdx, abcdy

I already understand that if I fetch the data at hash abcd by doing a firebase read at [a][b][c][d] I will also get the data under [a][b][c][d][x] and [a][b][c][d][y] if they exist

But if i do a fetch at [a][b][c][d][x], I'd like to confirm that no read/fetch occurs at the [d] root and instead firebase directly starts reading from the [x] root. Is my understanding correct here? or is each index [a] through [x] triggering a fetch? (that would be incredibly bad)

If this works in my current understanding, then Im fine with the other constraint regarding the security and permissions

And if someone curious would still like to know, the max hash size I can see using is 9 or 10 at the most.

Comment: Have you tried to doing so? I consider that solution myself